# Creating an Android Test project in Eclipse

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

How do I create an Android Test project in Eclipse in the target project's `/test` directory?

Note: I'm just doing my own Q+A for people according to the Stackoverflow FAQ on answering your own question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I am using Helios with the latest current version of Android (10.0.1)

The [Android Testing fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html) recommends you 
place the tests in the same project folder as your `src` folder. Some people have recommended that you create a new test project in its own folder so it doesn't get packaged into the apk.
I looked inside my apk and I don't think the test stuff was included (but I could be wrong). I like having it in the same directory as its more convenient for revision control - you don't need to sync two projects each time.

Assume we want to create a test suite for the `MyAndroidApp` project

Goto File.. New.. Other.. Android...Android Test Project

- Set "Test Project Name" to  `MyAndroidAppTest`
- For Test Target, choose "An existing Android project".. Use the Browse button to select `MyAndroidApp`
- Unselect "Use default location". This changes the location to be inside the MyAndroidApp project under the `tests` directory
- Click Finish

When it is being created, if you get a `An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing workspace".` error (or other errors) just ignore it. Click OK.

-Clean the `MyAndroidApp` project

Even though the project is in the `<workspace path>/MyAndroidApp/tests` directory it will appear as a normal Eclipse project in the package explorer.
Clean the `MyAndroidAppTest` project.
This worked for me.

**EDIT**

If you upload to SVN in Eclipse (by syncing the `MyAndroidApp` project, not the `MyAndroidAppTest` project) you need to do a little more (I've just done it now).
So when you *update* your other working copy it will pull down the `/tests` directory.
The `MyAndroidAppTest` project does not automatically show up in the Package Explorer.
So you need to go to File.. Import...Existing Projects into Workspace....
Then select the root directory by browsing to your `<workspace path>/MyAndroidApp/tests` directory and click Finish.

Comment: Works fine. No SVN issues for me. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, Helios, Subclipse and Unfuddle.

Comment: When I do this, I get the test project in a subdirectory "MyAndroidAppTestTest" (yep with two Tests) rather than "tests".

Comment: @Kurt if you rename your "MyAndroidAppTestTest" to "tests" and then create new project from existing source and then again the new created project to "MyAndroidAppTest" problem solved.

Comment: I have the same problem than @Kurt, is this a bug ?.

Comment: I also have the same problem as @Kurt and Sergio, and I agree it seems like a bug. If you have this problem too, please star the bug report I have created here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54876

Comment: Btw, @pharaoh, please could you explain exactly the steps you meant when you advised to "create new project from existing source"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: My project is for some reason not added properly and I get following error when trying to run (it can't run the correct project): Activity does not specify a android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner instrumentation or does not declare uses-library android.test.runner in its AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

I found here a very detailed solution to this problem. It seems to be an ADT bug.

<strike>http://jonblack.org/2012/11/24/creating-an-android-test-project-within-a-project</strike>

Still, when I import the test project back into the workspace at Step 5 I get the following error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\projects\MyApp\com.myapp.test-test\project.properties ( The system could not finde the file specified ).
```

I simply closed the error dialog and the test project appeared in my workspace at the same level as my android project, but the location was correctly set to MyApp/tests.
So I wrote a test, run it and it worked.