# Adding an android test project to current android project in SVN

Tags: android, svn, testing, project

As the title implies I have an android project in a repository that I want to add an android test project to. I would like to have both these two projects in my repository so they can be in sync and I only have to update one of the projects to update them both. I can't seem to figure out how to do it though. Is it possible? And if so, how can it be done?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thanks! That's what I've been looking for.

Comment: are you asking about how to add a folder to an existing repository or how to add a test project to a current project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your test project, do the following in Eclipse: Team > Share project > SVN.

And follow Tim's advice on how to import the project into eclipse.

See the following:

[Creating an Android Test project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395216/creating-an-android-junit-test-project-in-eclipse)

> If you upload to SVN in Eclipse (by syncing the MyAndroidApp project, not the MyAndroidAppTest project) you need to do a little more (I've just done it now). So when you update your other working copy it will pull down the /tests directory. The MyAndroidAppTest project does not automatically show up in the Package Explorer. So you need to go to File.. Import...Existing Projects into Workspace.... Then select the root directory by browsing to your /MyAndroidApp/tests directory and click Finish.
>
> By: Tim