# Creating a JUnit test for Android inside of Eclipse using the suggested directory structure

Tags: android, eclipse, junit

If you read: 
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#TestProjectPaths

It will tell you to create your tests inside your project at the same level as src. What it doesn't tell you is how to do it.

I checked out a post on here about this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395216/creating-an-android-junit-test-project-in-eclipse) and found that it no longer seems to work on newer versions of Eclipse (Indigo for example).

So, how can you set up the project as they suggest so that the test directory is inside of the original project?

Note that if you do as the link suggests and uncheck the use default location, then Eclipse will prevent you from going forward as it gripes that you overlap the location of an existing project.  If you try to add a sub-directory manually to place your project, then you can go on but you will get an error later saying "An internal error occurred while refreshing workspace" and no test project gets created.

Surely there is a way to do this isn't there or should I just disregard the suggested package structure and go with what Eclipse seems to want to do?

Comment: The most errorless and simplest way to do is detach the projects from your IDE, move/change the directory structure, then re-import them into IDE.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that might be the way to go but thought there should be a way to do it in Eclipse.